# Unique Constraint in Couchdb

Tags: couchdb

Is there any way to apply unique constraint in `couchdb`?

Suppose I have a document which have some fields like `email`, `emp_id`, `phone_number` that needs to be unique throughout the document. I could not find any way. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Any answer/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couchdb - how to set a field containing unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531624/couchdb-how-to-set-a-field-containing-unique-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of searching, I found that If you want to add a unique constraint to only one parameter you can set it as id. But If there are multiple parameter that needs to be unique, then this is not possible in couchdb

Answer (score 1):

The only unique constraint in CouchDB is on the document ID.  If you can put the unique components of your data in the document ID, then you have a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: @Filmzy, how can I put multiple components in documentID?

Comment: That's up to you. Your id can be any valid string. Something like "123-456" would be the obvious way to include ids 123 and 456.